# Replace a value with a new value in template

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates, kops

I'm learning how to use the replace function within go templating but I'm running into an issue.

I have my template build this:

```
  - cpuRequest: 200m
    etcdMembers:
    - instanceGroup: master-us-east-1a
      name: us-east-1a
    - instanceGroup: master-us-east-1d
      name: us-east-1d
    - instanceGroup: master-us-east-1f
      name: us-east-1f
```

and I want it to build this:

```
  - cpuRequest: 200m
    etcdMembers:
    - instanceGroup: master-us-east-1a
      name: a
    - instanceGroup: master-us-east-1d
      name: d
    - instanceGroup: master-us-east-1f
      name: f
```

I'm currently using this function:

```
  {{ range $i, $az := .availability_zones }}
    - instanceGroup: master-{{ . }}
      name: {{  . | replace $.region "" }} {{/* converts us-east-1a to a */}}
  {{ end }}
```

Unfortunately what I'm doing is not converting us-east-1a to just a. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is it doing instead? Have you already confirmed that `$.region` contains what you think it does? Editing your question to add the troubleshooting info in the only way you're going to get any help with this super vague question

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, I'm still pretty new to this. I figured out that the region value was not being filled causing the replace function to not act appropriately..

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the region value was not being filled causing the replace function to not act appropriately..